# SQL COUNT- not a single group group function error

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, aggregate-functions

I run the following `COUNT(*)` query on `Oracle DB`:

```
select count(*) + (select count(*) from t_diagram)  from t_object
```

I get the following error:

> Not a single group- group function.

I understand that using aggregation methods (e.g. `SUM`, `AVG`) require a `GROUP BY` statement.
However, how can I add a `GROUP BY` in a `select COUNT (*)` query?

Another challenge: The application I run the query on, does not suppport DUALs. It supports SELECT statements only. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to give us more information.  `COUNT(*)` is an aggregate, and will be applied to each group in the query.

Comment: Can you please post the exact query, using only `count(*)` should not give this error.

Comment: alone `select COUNT(*) from table` won't give you this error. You must be doing something else as well. Show your full query.

Comment: What is this query? What is your inner query doing?  
or do you need count(*) of both tables i.e. `t_object` and `t_diagram`? or you need count(*) based on some condition?

Comment: @AmneshGoel, This is a sum of 2 counts

Comment: Giorgi has posted an answer for you, and it will work. Check that please.

Comment: @AmneshGoel, I tested it. Does not work for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79614/discussion-between-amnesh-goel-and-user3165438).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a derived table?

```
select sum(cnt)
from
(
select count(*) as cnt from t_object
union all
select count(*) as cnt from t_diagram
) dt
```

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite as:

```
select (select count(*) from t_object) + (select count(*) from t_diagram) from dual
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d588/1

Comment: @GiorgyNakeuri, Thanks, In theory it should work (I unserstand dual  is temporary table ) , but in reality- it makes the application fail.

Comment: The application simply crushed down. Any ideas?

Comment: It is not because of select...Select should work fine. Embed your code in try catch blocks and debug.

Comment: @user3165438, I don't know what app you are using but, dual is supported by Oracle engine. Oracle will give just a one row with one column. Dual has no busineess with your app, Oracle does. May be you shoud just alias the expression? `select (select count(*) from t_object) + (select count(*) from t_diagram) AS SomeName from dual`

Comment: Thanks. Works great, but instead of retreiving the sum of counts, it just chaining the results. Any other approach?

Comment: What do you mean by chainig?

Comment: I mean concatenation. t_obejct count is 1, t_diagram count is 4, instead of getting 5 I get 14.

Comment: Can you try this:  `select cast((select count(*) from t_obejct) as int) + cast((select count(*) from t_diagram) as int) AS SomeName from dual`

Comment: The same result.  Thanks a lot for the time and effort! I upvoted.

Comment: Try one more `select ((select count(*) from t_obejct) + (select count(*) from t_diagram)) AS SomeName from dual`

Comment: I try, the same result.

Comment: Yes, It should. Quite frustrating. Thanks a lot.